# How can I render Childs in react with useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have a basic React code that create an empty list and fill it with data from the db with an useEffect. My problem is that when I try to make a map with the elements and render a new component, if I use an useState I can't do it.

Here is my code:

```
import "./../../../../assets/styles/logged/pedidos/pedidos.min.css"
import { Context } from "../../../../App";
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { PedidoCamionInterface } from "../../../../domain/entities/pedido_camion/pedido_camion_interface";


export function Pedidos() {
    const providers = useContext(Context);
    const [pedidos, setPedidos] = useState<PedidoCamionInterface[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        //TODO
        providers.providers.pedidosDb.getPedidosCamion([1, 2, 3], "").then((pedidos) => {
            setPedidos(pedidos);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Pedidos de camión</h1>
            <div id="pedidos">
                {pedidos.map((pedido: PedidoCamionInterface) => { return pedidoDiv(pedido); })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


const pedidoDiv = (pedido: PedidoCamionInterface) => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState<boolean>(false);

    return (
        <div className={`pedido ${selected ? "selected" : ""}`} key={pedido.idPedido}>
            <span>{pedido.nombrePedido}</span>
            <span>{pedido.tienda}</span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by Pedidos. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useContext                 useContext
2. useState                   useState
3. useEffect                  useEffect
4. undefined                  useState
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Pedidos@http://localhost:5173/src/ui/pages/logged/pedidos/pedidos.tsx?t=1667424544020:22:31
RenderedRoute@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=396bef63:2437:7
Routes@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=396bef63:2746:7
Router@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=396bef63:2697:7
BrowserRouter@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=396bef63:3079:7
App@http://localhost:5173/src/App.tsx?t=1667424544020:30:35 react-dom.development.js:86:29
```

Thanks for all.

Be able to render the child

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might lie in the `.map()` function.
Instead of

```
{pedidos.map((pedido: PedidoCamionInterface) => { return pedidoDiv(pedido); })}
```

try

```
{pedidos.map((pedido: PedidoCamionInterface) => (<PedidoDiv pedido={pedido} />))}
```

so React knows to render the component.

Also, change

```
const pedidoDiv = (pedido: PedidoCamionInterface) => {
```

to

```
const pedidoDiv = ({ pedido }: PedidoCamionInterface) => {
```

so the property `pedido` is destructured.